# I am trying to populate a UL in a Div with 20 random images from a directory

Tags: php, jquery, html, image

I have a div with an UL list in there, which currently has 20 images in, all named 1.jpg - 20.jpg.

I wanted to change this and have the images displayed in a random order on each page load / refresh.. I was wondering if you are able to help point me in the right direction?

All the images are on the webserver in "images/"

At the moment I need the images to fall in line with the below code:

```
<li><a></a><a><img alt="" src="images/Random1.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a></a><a><img alt="" src="images/Random2.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a></a><a><img alt="" src="images/Random3.jpg" /></a></li>
<li><a></a><a><img alt="" src="images/Random4.jpg" /></a></li>
```

At the moment I've tried several different bits of code I've seen on stack overflow, but I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried.

Comment: `range(1, 20)`, shuffle the result, loop over it & create the list items …

Answer (score 0):

```
$range = range(0,10); //how many pictures you have
shuffle($range);
foreach($range as $index => $value)
{
  echo "<li><a></a><a><img alt='' src='images/Random".$value.".jpg' /></a></li>";
}
```

Comment: Thank's for writing back! I'm getting the below error when putting the code in... any ideas?   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'as' (T_AS), expecting ';' in /var/sites/xxx/auto.php on line 20

Comment: the `for` should be `foreach` in that snippet.

Comment: Wanted to help fast, it was a mistake, it is foreach instead of for.